# Keep only part of string matching regular expression

Tags: regex, logstash, kibana

I have a regular expression for logging SQL errors contained in my log file:

```
SQLERR (SQL error =>[a-zA-Z]*)
```

The string "SQL error =>" is common to all SQL errors in my log file. What I am trying to do is to only keep and display the actual name of the error in Kibana (and not the text preceding it). This is what is currently displayed in my Kibana dashboard:

```
SQL error =>retryGetConnection
```

Any ideas?

Comment: regex would be `[a-zA-Z]*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a named capture to extract out the name:

```
SQLERR (SQL error =>(?<sqlError>\w+)
```

Then sqlError will be added to your event.

Answer (score 0):

You use regex:

```
SQL error =>(\w+)
```

with after the name of the error in $1

Comment: Thank you, but how should I use $1 in my logstash filter?

Comment: I don't know logstash, but if you have a link for the specific logstash filter documentation, I can see for you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, if you try to change the log, or just the show the log already in your file `SQL error =>retryGetConnection`

Comment: Basically my regex allows me to fetch any line that starts with "SQL error =>" in my log file, and this is perfect because I want to make a graph of these SQL errors. However, I don't want the graph to contain the "SQL error =>" string, but only the actual error name (that is following).